# PIG: error while using group

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to melt a trigram and count the number of occurrences of each word in PIG. I'm trying the following code in PIG but it throws an error on expecting a semi column and unexpected (.

An example of some input is as below:

```
567 word1 word2 word3
789 word2 word3 word5
706 word1 word5 word3
```

The code is as follows:

```
ht = load '/home/...../filename.txt' as=(cnt:chararray,w1:chararray,w2:chararray,w3:chararray); 
word1 = foreach ht generate $0,$1; -- creates a table of counts and word 1s 
word2 = foreach ht generate $0,$2; -- creates a table of counts and word 2s 
word3 = foreach ht generate $0,$3; -- creates a table of counts and word 3s 
sigma = union word1,word2,word3; -- creates a cumulative table listing words 1,2,3 on a single column; 
describe sigma; - this gives d:{cnt:int, w1:chararray) 
grp = group sigma by w1; 
wordcount = foreach grp generate group, sum(sigma$cnt)<-- this is where I get the error.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems like you are missing a semicolon at the end of the `FOREACH` for `wordcount`.  Also, you access `cnt` by `sigma.d.cnt`.

Comment: thanks mr2ert,I tried the actual script with the semi colon at the end of foreach but still have the error. also when I use sigma.d.cnt I get a 1070 error - could not resolve sum using imports. is there anything that Im doing wrong?

Comment: Oh yeah, `SUM` should also be in all capitals, builtin functions are case sensitive.